# Autocomplete Search gets slow and takes memory while it fetches the result from database

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

hello I have implemented an auto complete search on my app. I have cities stored in my mysql database and in app when user types any character or word, the app fetches result from the database and shows it. The problem which I am having is there are more then 1000 cities stored in database and when user lets say type one character my app keyboard got stuck a little  and it takes a lot of memory while it fetches the result and shows it. Is there any better way to implement this kind a functionality. Please Please look at my code and let me know what changes should I done in my code

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

        getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord)

        let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count; i++ {
            let cityname = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
        newTableData.append(cityname)
        }

        let array = (newTableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
        print("array is\(array)")
        filterTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Full Code:

```
class  CityTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var dict = NSDictionary()
    var filterTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()


    var newTableData = [String]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        self.resultSearchController = ({

            let controller  = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller


        })()

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

            return self.filterTableData.count
        }else {

            return dict.count
        }



    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CountryTableViewCell

        if(self.resultSearchController.active){

            cell.cityNameLabel.text = filterTableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell

        }else{

            cell.cityNameLabel.text = (((self.dict["\(indexPath.row)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
            return cell
        }



    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filterTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchWord = searchController.searchBar.text!

        getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord)

        let searchPredict = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        print("searchPredict is \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")

        for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count; i++ {
            let cityname = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
        newTableData.append(cityname)
        }

        let array = (newTableData as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredict)
        print("array is\(array)")
        filterTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }






    func getCityNamesFromServer(searchWord:String){


        let url:String = "http://localhost/"
        let params = ["city":searchWord]



        ServerRequest.postToServer(url, params: params) { result, error in

            if let result = result {
                print(result)

                self.dict = result

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to limit the amount of data is returned by adding a LIMIT clause to your query. Example SQL query:

```
SELECT name FROM cities WHERE name like '%something%';
```

Change this to:

```
SELECT name FROM cities  WHERE name like '%something%' LIMIT 10;
```

From the user point of view it does not make sense to return 1000 rows, you would not be able to display it anyways, therefore you have to come up with a number that fits on your screen. After any additional key press you can repeat the query  with the updated search string.

Comment: okay One small problem I am having is it shows same cities multiple times.is there any way to show only the distinct values. I mean from the database there is no duplicate entry but in tableview it shows same city multiple times.

Comment: You need to re-initialize the array between runs I guess.

Comment: well I done this but then it shows no records. empty 

 for var i = 0; i < self.dict.count - 1; i++ {
            newTableData = [String]()
            let cityname = (((self.dict["\(i)"] as?NSDictionary)!["City"] as?NSDictionary)!["name"] as?NSString)! as String
        
        newTableData.append(cityname)
        }

Comment: okay Okay I got it.. I have to reinitialize before the loop and it works. thank you very much for your double help :p